# Displaying output of a makefile with an included file

Tags: makefile

In my project a PHP/Symfony project, I have a Makefile which allows me to control my project.
I would like to use the variables in my .env.local file in my makefiles to run certain commands,
but I have a problem displaying the output.

I manage to recover my variables, my output display of the "make" command is different.

Before I had the list of my orders (with the description). AND now the equivalent, but with the name of the file "Makefile", without the name of the commands and just the description.

Output before:

```
Docker                       
-------------                
build                          Build the docker image
up                             Run the image
```

Output after:

```
Makefile:##Docker              
Makefile:##-------------       
Makefile                       Build the docker image
Makefile                       Run the image
```

This is my Makefile :

```
include .env.local
export

$(info Projet $(PROJECT_NAME))

build: ## Build the docker image
build: docker-compose.yml inituser
    docker compose --env-file .env.local build 
.PHONY: build

up: ## Run the image
up: docker-compose.yml
    docker compose --env-file .env.local up -d
.PHONY: up
```

I tried to clean my .env.local with the comments, it didn't change anything.
Then I even emptied the .env.local, still the same.
Only when I remove the include does the output display go back to normal.

Comment: How are you running `make`?  What command line, exactly?

Comment: Are the variables set by your `.env.local` file set in the host shell from which you launch `make`?  Because if so (or if you make it so) then you should neither need to `include` that file nor to explciitly `export` the variables.

Comment: On the other hand, your recipes seem already to be referencing the `.env.local` file, so what additional benefit do you think you can obtain by `include`ing it into the makefile?  The `include` is risky.  Makefiles are not shell scripts, and Docker env file syntax is a restricted version of shell syntax that allows constructs `make` does not support.

Comment: completely unclear, how you produce the output in your question. tried  to reproduce it with your Makefile, outputs `Projet` (plus PROJECTNAME if defined) and the calls it makes. So how do you produce your output? it's very likely, that there lies the problem